# Not able to pass JSON data to autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json

Not able to figure out why this doesnt work:

```
$('#add').live('click',function(){
    var searchdata = 'id=vendor' + '&location=' + $('#locationname').text() ;

     $.get('functions', searchdata, function(data){

       var source = $.parseJSON(data);

       $("#vendorselect").autocomplete({
         source: source
       });
    });



});
```

the `$.get` simply returns a JSON data like the following

> [{"value":"2","label":"A"},{"value":"2","label":"B"}]

finally this worked:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "functions",
                    type: "get",
                    data: 'id=vendor' + '&location=' + $('#locationname').text() ,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function( data ) {
                        vendor = $.map(data, function( val, i ) {
                                return {
                                    label: val.vendor_ID,
                                    value: val.vendor
                                };});
                         $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                            source: vendor
                        });
                    }

    });
```

Comment: I assume you are using http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/?

Comment: You just *completely* changed the question.  This will only activate the autocomplete when you click on `#add`.

Comment: yes thats what i want to do...dont want to ajax everytime i type in the box

Answer (score 0):

The `source` function is passed two parameters, `(request, response)`.  The `request` is what the user typed, and `response` is a callback function.

Your `return` does *nothing* because it's inside of an AJAX call.  You cannot return from AJAX calls, as they are *asynchronous*.

What you need to do is, call the `response` function passed with the data from the AJAX call.  Try this:

```
$("#vendorselect").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    var searchdata = 'id=vendor';
    $.getJSON('functions', searchdata, response);
  }
});
```

Note: `$.getJSON` will call `$.parseJSON` for you.

Update: Your JSON response needs to be the format that the autocomplete expects:

```
[{"label":"A","value":"2"},{"label":"B","value":"3"}]
```

Take a look at the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: @calvin12: Your JSON response needs to be in the correct format.

Comment: So i update the code (I want to first get the data and then asing it to autocomplete. Please see the updated code. But still doesnt work:

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Do you see any errors?  Do you see the JSON request in your DevTools?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function. When I start typing in the box.